# Ajax form not submitting form rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using a super basic google form on my website. I'm using this website to extract the HTML to display it on my website - http://stefano.brilli.me/google-forms-html-exporter/

Once I hit submit, nothing happens. The page is just locked. I'm trying to resubmit it to another page. Here is my code

```
<div class="row">
    <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfJQ9EkDN8aggSL9AEB2PK4BGiZgBzLDbS1IPppfSkU1zy-oA/formResponse"target="_self" id="bootstrapForm" method="POST">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <input id="679075295" type="text" name="entry.679075295" class="form-control" >  
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">  
            <input id="897968244" type="text" name="entry.897968244" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"> 
            <input id="685661947" type="text" name="entry.685661947" class="form-control" > 
        </div>
        <input id="503500083" type="hidden" name="entry.503500083" value="<%= @investment.id %>" >
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">  
            <button type="submit" value"submit" class="btn btn--primary type--uppercase" >Get Started</button> 
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here is the ajax script

```
    <script>
        $('#bootstrapForm').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault()
            var extraData = {}
            $('#bootstrapForm').ajaxSubmit({
                data: extraData,
                dataType: 'jsonp',  // This won't really work. It's just to use a GET instead of a POST to allow cookies from different domain.
                error: function () {
                    // Submit of form should be successful but JSONP callback will fail because Google Forms
                    // does not support it, so this is handled as a failure.
                    alert('Form Submitted. Thanks.')
                    // You can also redirect the user to a custom thank-you page:
                    window.location = 'http://reif.com.au/thankyou'
                }
            })
        }) 
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Any news from the browser developer tools' console?

Comment: nope, that nothing there either

Comment: I'm not sure, that was what i was given from that extraction website

Comment: yeah ok jsonp is required

Comment: you should add a `success` callback though :)

Comment: @apneadiving it's explained in the source comments why there's no `success` callback

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thanks man, tried that one too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feeling a little silly on this one. Essentially i didn't copy over all of the scripts. I was rushing through.. ALWAYS number 1 error!

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.2.2/jquery.form.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pjr1OlpZMY6qesJM68t2v39t+lMLvxwpa8QlRjJroA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This is what i needed to add, it now successfully submits and redirects!